Utilize copied assets for Trunk web app in Rust code
I am working on a simple web app using trunk where I would like to copy several JSON file assets for runtime use in some Rust code. I saw this example where they use the copy-dir to link assets, but in the example those assets are only being utilized in the HTML. How can I access those assets in Rust code?
I was hoping I could use fs::read_dir to get all the assets in my copied directory, but so far that has only had the effect of stalling out the app, and I can understand maybe that shouldn't be used in the web app, so I'm left wondering what should I be doing to access those files from Rust code and not just in the HTML?

I'm pretty sure you need to use the web APIs like fetch to load them.

When HTML references an asset exported by copy-dir, the browser automatically performs a network transaction to download it.
The Rust equivalent would be using the fetch API:
pub async fn fetch_string(url: &str) -> Result<String, String> {
    let opts = RequestInit::new();
    opts.set_method("GET");
    opts.set_mode(RequestMode::Cors);
    let request = Request::new_with_str_and_init(url, &opts).map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e))?;
    let window = web_sys::window().unwrap();
    let js_response = JsFuture::from(window.fetch_with_request(&request))
        .await
        .map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e))?;
    let response: Response = js_response.dyn_into().map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e))?;
    let text_promise = response.text().map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e))?;
    let text: String = JsFuture::from(text_promise)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| format!("{:?}", e))?
        .as_string()
        .ok_or(String::from("text not string"))?;
    Ok(text)
}

future_to_promise(async {
    let _json = json_fetch("/path/to/data.json").await.unwrap();
    Ok(JsValue::UNDEFINED)
});

Here's a crate with a higher-level fetch API: gloo_net.
There is, however, an alternative. You can use the include_str! macro to inline JSON into your Rust source code at compile time:
let json: &'static str = include_str!("./data.json");

A limitation of include_str! is that it only supports single, named files and not directories. For directories, you can use include_dir or rust_embed.

Very helpful answer, thanks a lot! As a short-term solution I ended up using include_dir, I'm not sure yet if that's the best solution for me but it works for now and I'll reference your other suggestions when I circle back.

include_dir seems as good or better than the ones I listed; I edited my answer to include it!
